# How to get duration of Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want a duration taken by a Job to complete a build in Jenkins. I tried to parse a Jenkins REST API. But the time when I read the value while a build is being executed it shows as 0.

Is there any method in Jenkins API where I can get this duration in which Jenkins job finished. I know the job is still running. But, I want to know is there a way.

Comment: you want the duration of the running job , or get the duration of other jobs ?

Comment: I wanted the duration of running Job. But no worries, for now, I got a workaround. Still, if someone knows API method please answer.